# ModuleNotFoundError no module named in Terminal on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, modulenotfounderror

I am very new to python and still learning how it all works. I'm building a tiny card game for a python class and decided to build it using Sublime Text and Github to teach myself how it all works.

The (very small) directory looks like this:

```
/GitHub
├── python-practice
└── war
    ├── __init_.py
    ├── __main__.py
    ├── config
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── card.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── deck.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   └── player.cpython-38.pyc
    │   ├── card.py
    │   ├── card.pyc
    │   ├── deck.py
    │   ├── deck.pyc
    │   ├── deck_test.py
    │   └── player.py
    └── game
        ├── __init__.py
        └── logic.py
```

But no matter if I use the compiler in terminal or the system interpreter in sublime to run logic.py it always comes back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game/logic.py", line 1, in <module>
    import card, deck, player
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'card'
```

...even though it's clearly there. I've tried `from config import card, deck, player` and I've also tried `import config`.

It would be easy and simple to just put all my modules in one folder but I'm trying to teach myself directories so it feels important that I figure this out. **How do I get my script to correctly import modules from another folder adjacent to it in the same directory? What am I missing?**

edit: adding my code from the modules below.

**card.py**

```
values = {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 'Eight':8, 'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':11, 'Queen':12, 'King':13, 'Ace':14}
suits = ('Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Clubs')
ranks = ('Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten','Jack','Queen','King','Ace')

class Card():
    def __init__(self,suit,rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
        self.value = values[rank]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank+" of "+ self.suit
```

**logic.py** (unfinished, WIP)

```
from config.card import Card
from config.deck import Deck
from config.player import Player

#Game setup

player_one = player.Player("One")
player_two = player.Player("Two")

new_deck = deck.Deck()
new_deck.shuffle()


for x in range(26):
    player_one.add_cards(new_deck.deal_one())
    player_two.add_cards(new_deck.deal_one())

game_on = True 

round_num = 0 

while game_on:

    

    if len(player_one.all_cards) == 0:
        print('Player One, out of cards! Player Two Wins!')
        game_on = False
        break
    elif len(player_two.all_cards) == 0:
        print('Player Two, out of cards! Player One Wins!')
        game_on = False
        break
    else:
        round_num+=1
    print(f'Round {round_num}')

    #NEW ROUND
    player_one_cards = []
    player_one_cards.append(player_one.remove_one())
    
    player_two_cards = []
    player_two_cards.append(player_two.remove_one())



    pass
```

Comment: try `from config.card import ...`

Comment: @WaveShaper Just did, and it couldn't locate any of them.

Comment: can you post the code of `card.py` and `logic.py`

Comment: @WaveShaper added!

Comment: after importing player as `from config.player import Player` use `Player` not  `player.Player` same goes for other classes too.

Comment: Thank you, I will update those once I can solve this import error.

Comment: look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.append(str(Path('.').absolute().parent))

from config.card import Card
from config.deck import Deck
from config.player import Player
```

This basically allows you to import stuff from the parent directory, which is what you need.